# How to stub Searchkick in search method in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, searchkick, rspec-mocks

I am new to RSpec. I want to test my search controller. I try to stub my search method in the controller but it always fails.

```
 Failure/Error: expect(Doctor).to receive(:search).with(search_param)
   (<Doctor(id: integer, name: string, address: string, phone: string, is_active: boolean, field_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, email: string, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: inet, last_sign_in_ip: inet, roles: integer, description: text, avatar_file_name: string, avatar_content_type: string, avatar_file_size: integer, avatar_updated_at: datetime, avatar_processing: boolean, title: string, valid_doctor: boolean, verification_photo_file_name: string, verification_photo_content_type: string, verification_photo_file_size: integer, verification_photo_updated_at: datetime) (class)>).search("rizky")
       expected: 1 time with arguments: ("rizky")
       received: 0 times
```

What's the correct way to isolate Searchkick?

Here is my search method in the controller:

```
def search
    @doctors = []
    keyword = params[:keyword]
    @doctors = call_search_in_doctor(keyword) if keyword.present?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @doctors, status: 200 }
      format.html { render 'users/search/index.html.haml', status: 200 }
    end
end

def call_search_in_doctor(keyword)
  Doctor.search keyword,
                misspellings: { edit_distance: 3 },
                page: params[:page],
                per_page: 10,
                limit: 100,
                fields: [{ name: :word },
                         { name: :word_start },
                         { name: :word_middle },
                         { name: :word_end },
                         :code, :field_name]
end
```

And here is my controller test:

```
context 'with keyword' do
  let(:search_param) { "rizky" }
  let(:doctor) { instance_double(Doctor) }
  let(:results) { instance_double(Searchkick::Results) }

  before do
    allow(Doctor).to receive(:search).with(search_param) {:results}
  end

  it 'calls Doctor.search' do
    get :search, search_param
    expect(Doctor).to receive(:search).with(search_param)
  end
end
```

Thanks for your precious time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSpec isn't saying that `Doctor.search` wasn't called, it's saying that it wasn't called with the arguments you specified. Your production code calls `Doctor.search` with two arguments (the search term and the hash of parameters), but your test allows `Doctor.search` to be called with only one argument (the search term).

You can fix it either by

- adding the second argument to the `with` calls in your test (if you think it's relevant to the test to check what that hash is), or
- adding a second argument of `anything` to those calls (if you think the hash is irrelevant to the test and just want to ignore it)

Comment: thanks! You are correct. That was also my mistake, the other mistakes were:
1. I should put get after expect.
2. Since I am using query string, I should put get :search, keyword: searchparam